# Python: How do I include multiple text files in my code?

Tags: python, text-files

I'm using Python3 on windows. How do I include multiple text files so that I can run my code using more than one file?

```
article_one = re.findall('\w+', open('D.txt',).read().lower())
wordbank = {}

for word in article_one:
    word = word.lower().strip(string.punctuation)
    if word not in wordbank:
        wordbank[word] = 1
    else:
        wordbank[word] += 1

sortedwords = sorted(wordbank.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

for word in sortedwords:
    print (word[1], word[0])​
```

Comment: What format are your files in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

In this example, you can create filelist as you want - may be using glob, or any other ways. if you need assistance - please tell your criteria on creating it.

```
filelist = ['D.txt','E.txt']
wordbank = {}
for file in filelist:
    article_one = re.findall('\w+', open(file,).read().lower())

    for word in article_one:
        word = word.lower().strip(string.punctuation)
        if word not in wordbank:
            wordbank[word] = 1
        else:
            wordbank[word] += 1

sortedwords = sorted(wordbank.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

for word in sortedwords:
    print (word[1], word[0])​
```

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you could just concatenate your files together before doing the regex, or just loop through the files.  You can also use the [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) dictionary to get the word frequency in the `word` list.

```
from collections import Counter

words = []
for filename in ['A.txt', 'D.txt']:
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        words.extend(re.findall('\w+', f.read().lower()))

wordbank = Counter(words)

for word, cnt in wordbank.most_common():
    print word, cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "glob" library to get an array of all the files that match an expression (ie *.txt). Once you have that array, you can then iterate over it, opening each file one by one and executing the steps you're trying to do.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html